# problem filtering pyspark dataframe if contains ">" or "<"

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

My data frame has `value` column containing `>` or `<` and I want to remove them.

This is my code:

```
df1= df.filter((col("value").contains('>') | col("value").contains('<')))
df2= df.filter(~(col("value").contains('>') | col("value").contains('<')))
print(df.count())
print(df1.count())
print(df2.count())
```

My result:

```
3900000
202
3600000
```

My expectation is:

```
df.count() = df1.count() + df2.count()
```

But it is not. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly caused by null values in `value` column.

`df.count()` counts all the rows in the Dataframe and nulls counted too. But when you use `contains` in the filter, null values are skipped.

**Example**:

```
data = [("value1_>", ), ("value2_>", ), ("value3_<",), ("value4",), (None,)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['value']) 

df1 = df.filter((col("value").contains('>') | col("value").contains('<')))
df2 = df.filter(~(col("value").contains('>') | col("value").contains('<')))
print(df.count())
print(df1.count())
print(df2.count())

#5
#3
#1
```